# Smart Servo Motor Type Comparison

Tags: motor, servomotor, serial, dynamixel

I have been using the standard MG90/SG90 servo motors for years now and am familiar with them. Recently, I am trying to build a robot dog with them with no success. The motors keep on vibrating and can't handle any load. They also use up all the I/O on my Arduino. The gears on the servos also constantly break. (Note: My MG90 still has plastic gears for some reason). That is why I have been looking into Smart Servos. Correct me if I am wrong:

- The motors use a Serial bus to communicate with each other and the
  Arduino.
- You can individually control them and they can do 360 rotation as well as standard 180.
- They can also send motor status like angle, mode, and current draw back to the Arduino.
- Most of them also have a lot of torque and metal gears.

If I am correct so far, could you please explain the difference between the following motors:

- LewanSoul/HiWonder LX-16A
- Robotis Dynamixel XL330-M077-T
- Robotis Dynamixel XL330-M288-T

Also, would switching over to Smart Motors resolve my issues.

Comment: what are the differences that you do not understand? ... which datasheets are you looking at?